# Why not use the key exchange algorithm for encryption?

Tags: encryption

Why not use the key exchange ( like Diffie–Hellman) algorithm for the actual encryption?
(instead of using them only for key exchange)

Comment: You're building on a wrong premise. It can be used for encryption only: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Public_key

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] might be much better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

The key exchange algorithms are rather resource intensive, and the asymmetric properties aren't needed after the initial handshake, so they only get used to exchange a key, which then gets used to encrypt the main data using some symmetric encryption scheme.